# Have you been to London before / were you in London before?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

1. Is this your first time in London or **have you been** to London before?

vs

2. Is this your first time in London or **were you** in London before?

situation: a local is taking a tourist for a city tour. What should he ask him?

Comment: "Were you in London before?" is American; "Have you been to London before" is British.

Comment: been in or been to ?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I belive most Americans would still say "Have you been to this city before?"

Comment: I'm torn whether to close this question, but in the end I agree it's really a matter of opinion.  Both are equally acceptable.

Comment: I'm American (expat) and I strongly disagree with @MichaelHarvey. "Have you been to X before" is overwhelmingly preferred in Am.E.

Comment: Oh please. I am sick of seeing misguided AmE/BrE indications. "Have you been to x before? is most definitely not "British". It's universal in English by those who can actually speak it. And both are fine and dandy.

Comment: @Lambie: Michael Harvey has fallen into one of the errors that Lynne Murphy discusses in _The Prodigal Tongue_. We hear Americans saying A, where we would say B, and don't notice that Americans also say B. (The same error occurs the other way round too). _Were you in X before_ is unusual in BrE.

Comment: @ColinFine Were you in London before? has to be used if the person is no longer there. Imagine a police inquiry, as you say.

Comment: @Lambie: absolutely not. To Britons of my generation _Were you in London before_ is something we have heard on American media, but would not say. _Have you ever been in London_ (without the "before") if the person is not there. Or _Were you in London on (date)_. But not _Were you in London before_.

Comment: @ColinFine Were you in London before this? Come on, now. Let's not exaggerate. I'll agree about before without anything after it, as maybe being "AmE" but not: Were you in London before this? Or before this week? Or before this event. etc. In any case, **before** on its own is spoken, not usually written It's informal.

Comment: That said: Sir John Fortescue, feelingly bewails, because he is a counsellor whose like “never would be seen again, and certainly never had been in England before.” https://www.british-history.ac.uk/cal-cecil-papers/vol4/iii-xiii past perfect, but still....

Comment: @Lambie: Yes. _never has/have/had been in London before_ is fine.

Comment: @ColinFine  Oh, you can have before on the end but you can't have it with: "Were you in London early? Late? Before?", the detective insisted. Answer: Yes, sir, I was here last week. Palease.....:)

Answer (score 1):

**Watch how this typically works:

**FIRST Scenario**
Person One:  **Have you been** to London before? [You are still there, and no one cares when you got there.]
Person Two: Yes, **I've been here before**.
Person One: Really? **When did you come** to London before?
Person Two: I came to London last year.

**Notice the switch from present perfect to simple past above**. That is a very usual **pattern** of speech.

**SECOND Scenario**
Person One:  **Were you** in London before? [before this time]. You seem to know your way around.
Person Two: Yes, **I was here** before. I was here last summer.

Either one is fine. In the second one, Person One is asking about a specific time when Person Two might have been in London. In the first, the question is more open ended.
Note that in the Second Scenario, the question could also be asked to Person Two when she or he is no longer in London.

Answer (score -1):

To explain the difference we must add several words to each example:
*- Do you know how to get to the Trafalgar Square from here?*
*‐ Yes, of course. I must take to the right from the nearest corner and go for half a mile straight.*
*– Well. You're perfectly right. Is this your first time in London or have you been to London before?*

*‐ What do you want to see in London ? Shopping in the Northern, maybe, if you prefer. Or, something of a Tatler style, high fashion boutiques, I mean, if you like ?*
*Is this your first time in London or were you in London before?*

In the first case, we explain the events of the present by that  some events happened in the past. In the second, the emphasis is on the fact that the action really happened in the past.

Comment: "I must take to the right from the nearest corner and go for half a mile straight" is not idiomatic English.

Comment: Neither is: how to get to the Trafalgar Square

Comment: This is something to add to the subject.
*Now let's start heading toward the village, which I think I know how to get to from here. But who's to know? Iasin may be lost somewhere in some remote part of this ...*
Living on the Edge, Rosiland Miller, 2002.

*I decide to head towards the kitchen since it's the only other place I know how to get to from here. I walk around, admiring the sheer beauty of it again.*
Loving Olivia, M.C.Roman, 2016.

Comment: For those who may not be familiar.
*To take to* means *prefer*.
*The right* means *the right side* here. 
*To take to the right side* means the same as *prefer veering starboard*.  The jargon of transport workers.
*From the nearest corner* means *when walking from the nearest corner*. Jargon ellipsis.
Both interlocutors can watch the street corner that is in front of them.
It is an example of the specific  jargon. Even so, it is went down very well in the regions where people of some professions make up a large proportion of population. And it has long been the ordinary spoken speech.

Comment: There is no "to" in "take to the right". Yes, if someone **takes to something** it means they have grown to like it, but it's completely wrong for this context;  we are giving directions.  Instead the following is preferable:  "**take a/the** right onto [street name]" or just "**turn** right AT the nearest corner" P.S if you want to reply to users, place @ before their username e.g. @ColinFine

Comment: @Mari-Lou Thanks for your advice. I don't argue about the words of jargon because there is no evidence on the Web. But, about *know how to get to*, many examples could be found in the open resources on the net.

Comment: @kngram: Nobody is arguing about _know how to get to_. It was _**the** Trafalgar Square_ which Lambie was pointing out was not English. The English for the sentence I quoted is _I must turn right at the next corner and go straight on for half a mile_.

Comment: Actually, it is how we say now, it was how we said it long ago. Even in the written speech of  schoolbooks. There was no need to explain it in detail actually. The grammar construction is so widespread that everybody is able  to get it right without any effort. For example, *By convention, the quantities taken to the right and the ones taken to the left from a given point are considered positive.*(notereads. com, 2020), *... taken to the left from a line through income of about...* (WL Crum, 1935).

Comment: @Colin Fine Sorry. Are you serious? If a taxi driver said *Trafalgar square*, it would mean the square having this name. If a taxi driver said *the Trafalgar square* in the spoken speech, it would mean only the area around this square. It is an example of the spoken speech. Was it necessary to kick up a racket? Maybe, it would be better to clarify what the sentence mean.

Comment: @kngram: you must speak a different English from any I've ever heard. If I heard a taxi driver say _the Trafalgar square_ I would conclude that he was a foreigner whose English wasn't very good. If I heard somebody say _take to the right_ while giving directions, I would conclude that he was a foreigner whose English wasn't very good. If I heard somebody say _go half a mile straight_, I would conclude that he was a foreigner whose English wasn't bad, but who didn't have command of idiomatic expressions like _go straight on for half a mile_.

Comment: You have every right to have your own opinion. No one has any objections regarding these principles.
Here you are. Now it will be self-explanatory.
*The protesters knelt on their knees in the “Trafalgar Square” or “Trafalgar Square” in central London, chanting “No justice .. no peace”, and then they passed by the parliament headquarters until they reached the American embassy.*

Comment: *... and one half would take to the right, cross over and occupy the South-East side of the mountain, and that the other should advance to the North-West side...*
*Hazard markers tell you the direction to take when approaching the obstacle or driving past the hazard. You must obey these signs.*
*At home one could hardly go half a mile straight—there were curves, turns, alleys and back streets, and with the windows of the car rolled down.*